# 'ERROR in Cannot read property 'listLazyRoutes' of undefined' Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

Buen dia para todos, alguno sabe de que manera puedo solucionar este error al lanzar ng serve de Angular 2, estoy tratando de crear las carpeta dist con sus archivos para producción[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @JuanFajardo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías agregar tu código en la pregunta, de lo contrario es imposible tener una respuesta concreta a tu pregunta. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es que puedas agregar un [mcve].

Comment: gracias Mariano por el aporte y por atender mi pregunta, revisare tus recomendaciones.